# Separating callback from other modules

Tags: ros, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

May I want something strange, but it interesting programming problem.
So, I wrote class-wrapper Sensor that subscribes on topic (like /camera/image) and in callback receives data (like this->callback(Image& data), node.subscribe(..., &Sensor::callback). Data should be prepared by some filters. At this moment, filters called in callback:

```
void Sensor::callback(Image& data)
{
Image* newData;
newData = filter1(data);
newData = filter2(newData);
...
}
```

But I think it is not good. Is there way to separate them from Sensor? Something like this:

```
data = Sensor.getData();
data = filter1(data);
data = filter2(data);
```

I think that I missed simple idea of this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31609/separating-callback-from-other-modules/) by [CaptainTrunky](https://answers.ros.org/users/1038/captaintrunky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 546 on 2012-04-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Similar things have been done in ROS and other libraries already. You can either use and extend existing implementations or take them as examples on how the design could look like. Have a look at [filters](http://ros.org/wiki/filters), [pcl_ros](http://ros.org/wiki/pcl_ros), the [pcl_ros tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl_ros/Tutorials) and [pcl](http://pointclouds.org/) including its [tutorials](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CaptainTrunky](https://answers.ros.org/users/1038/captaintrunky/) on 2012-04-11**:
Thanks. Filters are exactly what I need.